# InvalidArgumentException not available in Silverlight 3 class library?

Tags: .net, silverlight, exception

I tried to throw an InvalidArgumentException in a Silverlight 3 class library, and this type is not available.  It doesn't even give me the red underline that tells me it's in a referenced assembly but I just need to import or fully qualify the namespace.  Do I have to import a whole other assembly just to get this exception class, or do I have to define my own by this name (or use a less relevant exception class from the choices available)?  Why wouldn't this just be available everywhere...it's a pretty universal condition.

Comment: Which `InvalidArgumentException`? What's the full type name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to use [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)?

> The exception that is thrown when one
>   of the arguments provided to a method
>   is not valid.

[`InvalidArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191580.aspx) appears to live in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` assemby and I am not sure if that is what you really want.

Comment: Thank you.  From the looks of it, I think I was expecting InvalidArgumentException because I've seen it so much being returned from SQL.  ArgumentException is just what I need.  =]